# Console output appears in the wrong order

Tags: c, gcc, console

I'm using win 8.1 64bit Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 and compiling with gcc 4.6.4 and the problem is e.g.

in this simple program, my `printf` and `scanf` statements are appearing on the console in the wrong order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int i;

    printf("Enter int: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Hello %d\n",i);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

it does this:

> 4
>
> Enter int: Hello 4

instead of this:

> Enter int: 4
>
> Hello 4

Comment: It's strange a little for me. Try `fflush(stdout);` after the first print

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` is buffered<sup>1</sup>.  That means when you call it, it *will not immediately print*.  Instead, it will store what you told it to print, and automatically print it when enough text has been stored in the buffer.

If you use a `\n` after in your print statement, it will automatically print the whole buffer (that's why the last call to `printf` prints everything).  For your case, you may want to use a manual flush with `fflush`

```
printf("Enter int: "); fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("Hello %d\n",i);
```

<sup>1</sup> Technically, it's `stdout` which is buffered, but it's easier to think of it as `printf` being buffered at this point.